# how to get action with specific url asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want get specific link to receive an action

this my controller :

```
namespace tabi.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult List(string name=null)
        {
            ViewBag.name = name;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

how to get action with this link :

```
/category/game
```

game is name parameter value

and don't change default route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't defined a custom route, you have to use the following url:

```
/Category/List?name=game
```

If you specify a custom route to allow List as the default action, and `/{name}` to the route (rather than ID), it would utilize the route you specified, such as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "game",
  url: "{controller}/{name}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "List" });
```

This route should support that URL.

Comment: my controller name in Category , plz give your me finaly code.and tell my how to use it exactly,thx.

Comment: Add the route I defined above, above the default route, which should allow you to do/Category/GameName - however, any spaces would need to be encoded or use dashes and you'll have to replace dashes with spaces, or something like that.